# Coset representatives of a principal congruence subgroup by another principal congruence subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, modular-forms, modular-group

Consider the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$, this consists of entries in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ congruent to the identity modulo $N$. Consider another principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(M)$ such that $N$ divides $M$, then $\Gamma(M) \subset \Gamma(N)$. Is there a formula for the representatives of the coset $\Gamma(M) / \Gamma(N)$? I know formulas for cosets of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ but have the cosets mentioned above been studied before? Does it have an "easy" answer?

Comment: This can be reduced to the same question with $\mathbb Z$ replaced by $p$-adic integers ${\mathbb Z}_p$ by using strong approximation.